# Macro to open multiple links in new tabs

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I want my macro to open each link stored in a spreadsheet in a separate IE tab. I am successful with opening the first link, but for some reason on the second iteration of the loop I get:

> Automation error.The interface is unknown
>   error.

I suspect the macro somehow loses IE object reference after first iteration, but I am not sure why.

Range is set OK.

Here is the code:

```
Sub OpenCodingForms()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim CodingFormLinks As Range
Dim IE as InternetExplorerMedium

Set wb1 = Workbooks("New shortcut.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Data")
Set CodingFormLinks = ws1.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

ws1.Activate

For Each link In CodingFormLinks.Cells
   IE.Navigate link, CLng(2049)
Next link

End Sub
```

Comment: I get multiple windows opening if i define link as Range and navigate to Link.Text and if i use 2048 i can have them open in new tabs of  existing window.

Comment: Try CLng(2048) instead of CLng(2049), also you might want to try a delay in the loop to allow the page to load - While IE.Busy | Do Events | Wend

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions, but to no avail, still the same error. However, if I move the `Set IE` and `IE.Visible` inside the loop, I manage to open all the links in new windows, but this is not a preferred solution.

Comment: From my experience, I don't think you can tell IE automation (through VBA) to open each new window in a tab, unfortunately. I also think I read somewhere why that is, but I don't have that link handy. (I hope I am wrong though, as that means, you get a good answer).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You can, I have some working code that does it. Have a look at the BrowserNavContants of the Flags parameter here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Absinthe - that link states IE7 ... `navOpenInBackgroundTab
Internet Explorer 7 ...` (doesn't say only, but also doesn't say *and later*). Maybe that is user's issue.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have it working in IE 10 & 11, I guess Qharr who posted above does too. I wasn't looking to contradict, just offering one for your toolkit :) I'm stumped as to why CLng(2048) doesn't work for OP. Sorry OP!

Comment: @Absinthe - Never thought you were contradicting :). I was just pointing out in case it helped OP. But good to know it works on later versions. Also, special thanks for pointing it out. Good to know its there if I need it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue before and ended up just writing a routine to get the instance.   You will need to add a reference to shell controls and automation.

you may have to adjust this to look for the sURL var in the beginning of the actual URL if there is redirection.

```
Sub OpenCodingForms()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim CodingFormLinks As Range
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("New shortcut.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Data")
    Set CodingFormLinks = ws1.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    ws1.Activate

    Dim sUrl As String
    For Each link In CodingFormLinks.Cells
       sUrl = link.Value
       IE.navigate sUrl, CLng(2048)
       Set IE = GetWebPage(sUrl)
    Next link

End Sub



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Desc: The Function gets the Internet Explorer window that has the current
'   URL from the sURL Parameter.  The Function Timesout after 30 seconds
'Input parameters:
    'String sURL - The URL to look for
'Output parameters:
    'InternetExplorer ie - the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
'Result: returns the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetWebPage(sUrl As String) As InternetExplorer
Dim winShell As Shell
Dim dt As Date
    'set the timeout period
    dt = DateAdd("s", 300, DateTime.Now)

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    'loop until we timeout
    Do While dt > DateTime.Now
        Set winShell = New Shell
        'loop through the windows and check the internet explorer windows
        For Each IE In winShell.Windows
            'check for the url
            If IE.LocationURL = sUrl Then
                'set the window visible
                IE.Visible = True
                IE.Silent = True
                'set the return value
                Set GetWebPage = IE
                Do While IE.Busy
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                Set winShell = Nothing
                Exit Do
            End If
        Next IE
        Set winShell = Nothing
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```